# Timestep in Geometric Brownian Motion

Tags: time-series, brownian-motion

I have some questions about mean and volatility.

I have historical **monthly** data of CO2 closing price(2013.01~2022.03), $p_{t}$  whose length is 111.

I preprocessed the data by computing $\ln{\frac{p_t}{p_{t-1}}}$ and have the data with 110 length to fit into GBM model.

My objective is to predict forward **240 months(=20 years)** from now (t0: 2022.03).

The sample mean($m$) and variance($v$) of 110 length of historical data were **0.0282** and **0.01912**.

I set $t=1 \,(20\,years)$, $\Delta t={\frac{1}{240}}$

Then, I watched the part of the video(14:00~15:00) indicated below and it told me that I should multiply 240 to obtain 20-years mean and 20-years variance.

Reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=98xF6b0PZpo&t=889s

I don't understand the intention of it.

(1) Isn't it okay just to use the sample mean and variance(or std) as $\mu=m=0.0282$ and $\sigma^2=v=0.01912$ in GBM model? or Do I have to multiply 240?

(2) The video(16:11) also told that $\mu=m+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}$, not $\mu=m$. I don't know which is the right way to compute $\mu$. Which one is right?

(3) I'm not sure my $t$ and $\Delta t$ are correctly set. As far as I know, $t=1$ is for a year in GBM, but in my case it is 20 years... Is my setting right?

### My python code is below (The version that just uses the sample mean and variance as $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os   

# Load monthly log-preprocessed CO2 price & compute sampling mean and variance
df = pd.read_excel('./CO2_Price_Data_EU_ETS_Phase3.xlsx') # data with CO2 closing price and its preprocessed version
sample_mean = df['Price Change (Relative, Log)'].mean()
sample_var = df['Price Change (Relative, Log)'].var()
sample_std = df['Price Change (Relative, Log)'].std()

mu = sample_mean
sigma_square = sample_var

# Some parameters
n_sims = 500
t = 1 # 20 years
dt = 1/240
N = 240

# Simulation using GBM model
X = np.zeros((N+1, n_sims))
X[0,:] = df['Closing Price'].iloc[-1]

for j in range(1, n_sims+1):
    for i in range(N):
        X[i+1, j-1] = X[i, j-1] * np.exp(mu*dt + np.sqrt(sigma_square) * np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.standard_normal())

# Plotting
tt = np.arange(N+1)
for k in range(X.shape[1]):
    plt.plot(tt, X[:, k])
```

Comment: General rule: when you add normal distributions, the resulting distribution is normal with a mean that's the sum of the means and a variance that's the sum of the variances. If you're using a 131 day window, you'd multiply by 365/131 for one year, 7300/131 for 20 years. However, assuming that a stock will continue to increase the same way it has in the last 131 days is a bit overly optimistic.

Comment: @BarryCarter I understand. I really appreciate it!